# HTTp post request in android

Tags: android, cookies, service, http-post

I am new to android. I was trying http post request but was getting connection failed . Below is the given code

```
private void postRequest(String givenUsername, String givenPassword) {

        String paramUsername = givenUsername;
        String paramPassword = givenPassword;

        System.out.println("*** doInBackground ** paramUsername " + paramUsername + " paramPassword :" + paramPassword);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // In a POST request, we don't pass the values in the URL.
        // Therefore we use only the web page URL as the parameter of the HttpPost argument
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url");
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-Length", "40");
        httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json,text/javascript, */*");
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // httpPost.s

        // Because we are not passing values over the URL, we should have a mechanism to pass the
        // values that can be
        // uniquely separate by the other end.
        // To achieve that we use BasicNameValuePair
        // Things we need to pass with the POST request
        BasicNameValuePair usernameBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("username", paramUsername);
        BasicNameValuePair passwordBasicNameValuePAir = new BasicNameValuePair("password", paramPassword);

        // We add the content that we want to pass with the POST request to as name-value pairs
        // Now we put those sending details to an ArrayList with type safe of NameValuePair
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairList.add(usernameBasicNameValuePair);
        nameValuePairList.add(passwordBasicNameValuePAir);

        try {
            // UrlEncodedFormEntity is an entity composed of a list of url-encoded pairs.
            // This is typically useful while sending an HTTP POST request.
            UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);

            // setEntity() hands the entity (here it is urlEncodedFormEntity) to the request.
            httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

            try {
                // HttpResponse is an interface just like HttpPost.
                // Therefore we can't initialize them
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                if (resEntity != null) {
                    Log.i("RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                }

                // According to the JAVA API, InputStream constructor do nothing.
                // So we can't initialize InputStream although it is not an interface
                InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                }

                System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
                List<Cookie> cookies = ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).getCookieStore().getCookies();
                if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("None");
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
                cookies = ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).getCookieStore().getCookies();
                if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("None");
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                    }
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                System.out.println("First Exception caz of HttpResponese :" + cpe);
                cpe.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("Second Exception caz of HttpResponse :" + ioe);
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            System.out.println("An Exception given because of UrlEncodedFormEntity argument :" + uee);
            uee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am sending username and password for my Login screen .and it will be returning me a cookie.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url");
```

Replace the `url` with your url

Edit:
Here is how I pass my url's:

```
String url_select = "http://www.yoururlgoeshere.com"
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);
```

Also, since I am on API Level 3.0+ I have to use HTTP Post using `AsyncTask`. Here is a [tutorial link](http://ugirusgiarto.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/json-php-mysql-with-asynctask-progressdialog/).

Answer (score 0):

This method works for every request. "POST" is given as String.

```
 * Sends generic HTTP calls: GET, POST, DELETE etc provided the parameters. Also includes the
 * response body in the returned object.
 */

private WebCallResponse sendRequest(String url, WebCallHeader[] headers,
        String method, byte[] postBytes) throws WebServiceException
        {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    URL serverUrl = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    InputStream is = null;

    try
    {
        serverUrl = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection)serverUrl.openConnection();   
        conn.setRequestMethod(method);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "deflated");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");

        if(headers != null && headers.length > 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i)
            {
                conn.setRequestProperty(headers[i].getHeaderName(), headers[i].getHeaderValue());
            }
        }

        //-- For POSTs and PUTs
        if(postBytes != null && postBytes.length > 0)
        {
            conn.setDoOutput(true); 
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postBytes.length));
            conn.connect();
            os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(postBytes);
        }

        //-- Execute happens here.
        final int rc = conn.getResponseCode();

        //-- Build return object from the response.
        final WebCallResponse wcr = new WebCallResponse();
        wcr.setStatusCode(rc);  

        if (conn.getHeaderField("record-count") != null)
        {
            final Vector headerVector = new Vector();
            headerVector.add(conn.getHeaderField("record-count"));
            wcr.setHeaders(headerVector);
        }

        is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        wcr.setResponseString(this.getResponseBody(is));

        return wcr;
    } catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        conn.getErrorStream();
        throw new WebServiceException(ioe, "Failed to open connection to host.");
    }finally    
    {
        try{if(is != null)is.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
        try{if(os != null)os.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
        try{if(conn != null)conn.disconnect();}catch(Exception squish){}
    }
}


public class WebCallResponse {
private int statusCode;
private String responseString;
private Vector headers;

public Vector getHeaders()
{
    return headers;
}
public void setHeaders(Vector headers)
{
    this.headers = headers;
}

public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public int getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

public void setResponseString(String responseString) {
    this.responseString = responseString;
}

public String getResponseString() {
    return responseString;
}

public boolean isRequestSuccessful(){
    return (statusCode >=200 && statusCode <300);
}

public String getHeaderValue(String key)
{
    WebCallHeader currentHeader;
    String result = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.headers.size(); i++)
    {
        currentHeader = ((WebCallHeader) this.headers.elementAt(i));
        if (currentHeader.getHeaderName().equalsIgnoreCase(key))
        {
            result = currentHeader.getHeaderValue();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public String toString()
{
    return this.responseString;     
}
```

}

```
public class WebCallHeader {
private String headerName;
private String headerValue;

public WebCallHeader(String name,String value)
{
    this.headerName = name;
    this.headerValue = value;
}

public void setHeaderName(String headerName) {
    this.headerName = headerName;
}

public String getHeaderName() {
    return headerName;
}

public void setHeaderValue(String headerValue) {
    this.headerValue = headerValue;
}

public String getHeaderValue() {
    return headerValue;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Eu Vid, can you tell us what you have implemented in above code and I am trying this code but WebCallResponce is showing error can you tell me us how to solve it.

Comment: Sorry for that, WebCallResponse is a model for the response that wraps  parameters. i'll update my response with that actual object.

Comment: I couldn't format the code quite well. You'll have to include the last brackets for the model classes.